# How to copy a folder by overwriting an existing folder and delete all the old content in Linux?

Tags: linux, cp, file-copy

I can use `rm` to delete the old folder, then use `cp` to copy the new folder. But how to do it in one go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --delete source/ target
```

This would delete all the contents of the directory `target` that does not match the contents of the directory `source`, and would additionally copy the contents of `source` there.

The trailing `/` at the end of `source/` is significant as without it, you would get a directory at `target/source` instead of making `target` a copy of `source`.

The `-a` (or `--archive`) option makes `rsync` copy timestamps and other metadata, and the `-v` (or `--verbose`) option makes `rsync` operate verbosely.  Without `--delete`, no existing contents in `target` would be deleted (unless it had the same name as things in `source` in which case it would be updated).

Answer (score 0):

That is one go. `rm -fr olddir/* ; cp -a newdir/* olddir`

Comment: Note that `*` would not by default match hidden names.